# Google Maps -> MapView -> creation of a constructor -> RuntimeException

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I try to write one application for Google Maps.

Tell me, what is my mistake?

If you write like this, all of the works, the card is loaded.

```
public class TravelMapActivity extends MapActivity {
  private MapView mapView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.travel_map_activity);
        mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.travelMapView);
    }
}
```

And if you create a constructor, I get these errors here.

```
    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.travel_map_activity);
    mapView = new MapView(this, getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_api_key));
}


 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{de.ai.mi.maptrack/de.ai.mi.maptrack.activities.TravelMapActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to have a single MapView in a MapActivity

 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You are only allowed to
 have a single MapView in a MapActivity
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the *v1 google maps android api* you only allowed one MapView at a time. You instantiate one MapView in your XML travel_map_activity i guess, so when you try to create another one with

```
mapView = new MapView(this, getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_api_key));
```

you get the Exception. Try remove the MapView from the XML to solve this.